# How to handle multiple push notifications? and i need to show one by one like tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, ios7

[image]

I want to show push notification like below image.

Comment: where u want to show

Comment: What did you tried? Show us your code.

Comment: If the push notification is delivered to the OS and not to your app (i.e. your app is not running, or is in the background and the pushes are not background pushes) then you have no control whatever over how they are displayed. If they are delivered to your app while your app is in the foreground then you can choose to display whatever you want in your GUI that represents them.

Comment: In my application i get more than 3 push notification means, i want to show like  gmail push notifications....

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible!! Even Steve Job come out from death, this multiple push notifications are impossible to exist!!

Comment: thanks @Dato' Mohammad Nurdin, but google did, just check ur gmail, Instagram, Dropbox and twitter push notification in your iphone....

Comment: No, there only one push notification. I'm always using gmail. They just combine all notifications into one.

Comment: are you checked twitter and Instagram push notification in your iPhone